# Php, get the values from a text box to the next page

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP Mysql, I am struck on this problem, My problem is I have a from with two textboxes (name, sal) and i got the values from mysql. Now I am making changes in the sal text box, i am making some changes int he form textboxes, I want to see the vlaues from this form which are changed or unchanged to another form. How to do it.

I am getting the Last row only as result not all the values from the text boses.

The code is

File Name:   emp.php

```
 <form name = "emp.php" action = "emp_new.php" >
 <?php
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $emp_name = $row["emp_name"];
  $emp_sal = $row["emp_sal"];
    echo "<input type='Text' name='$emp_name' value= '$emp_name' size='8' id='emp_name'>";
    echo "<input type='Text' name='emp_sal' value= '$emp_sal' size='8' id='emp_sal'>";  
     }
<input type=submit name="process" value="Process">
```

Clicking on the process i want to display all the content in the text boxes in page 
     emp_new.php

Answer (score 0):

use array element on the form like **emp_name[]**

```
<form name = "emp.php" action = "emp_new.php" method="post" >
 <?php
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $emp_name = $row["emp_name"];
  $emp_sal = $row["emp_sal"];
    echo "<input type='Text' name='emp_name[]' value= '$emp_name' size='8' id='emp_name'>";
    echo "<input type='Text' name='emp_sal[]' value= '$emp_sal' size='8' id='emp_sal'>";  
     }
<input type="submit" name="process" value="Process">
```

**on emp_new.php do the following**

```
$emp_name=$_POST['emp_name'];
$emp_sal=$_POST['emp_sal'];

foreach($emp_name as $key=>$val){
  $name=$val;
  $sal=$emp_sal[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just name the text boxex distinctly.. assuming that you have list of less than 100 employees.

```
 <form  method="post" action = "emp_new.php" >
  <?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");
 $name=1;
 $sal=100;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   $emp_name = $row["emp_name"];
   $emp_sal = $row["emp_sal"];
  echo "<input type='Text' name='$name++' value= '$emp_name' size='8' id='emp_name'/>";
  echo "<input type='Text' name='$sal++' value= '$emp_sal' size='8' id='emp_sal'/>";  
   }
 echo "<input type='hidden' value=$name name='size' />";
  ?>

 <input type=submit name="process" value="Process">
```

To access these value in new fom is use following code
in  new_emp.php

```
 <?php

 $name=1;
 $sal=100;
 for($i=1;$i<=$size;$i++)
 {
   $emp_name = $_post[$name];
   $emp_sal = $row["$sal];
  echo "<input type='Text' name='$name++' value= '$emp_name' size='8' id='emp_name'>";
  echo "<input type='Text' name='$sal++' value= '$emp_sal' size='8' id='emp_sal'>";  
   }
  ?>
```